# Docker containers cannot communicate using host public IP

Tags: networking, ubuntu, dns, iptables, docker

I have an Ubuntu server running some apps in Docker (including Nginx Proxy Manager) and some subdomains pointing to the public IP of my server. All my containers are on the same bridge network. One of the containers needs to make requests to other containers, and this requests should be made using the URL that points to the public IP of the host (e.g.: app1.mydomain.net), but the request never reaches its destination.

Trying to solve it, I found that when I run `ping app1.mydomain.net` or `curl -v app1.mydomain.net` in a terminal from my server, there always occurs timeouts after some minutes, but if I run the same commands on another PC, or the same commands but using different URLs that aren't pointing to the public IP of the host, I get successful responses.

Then I used `iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d [SERVER-PUBLIC-IP]/32 -j DNAT --to-destination [SERVER-PRIVATE-IP]` and now I can use `ping app1.mydomain.net` and `curl -v app1.mydomain.net` from the server and receive successful responses. But I think this isn't the right solution, because inside containers the timeouts still occurs as if nothing has changed.

After the iptables command, also I tried the following commands to test:

`docker run --rm curlimages/curl -L -v https://google.com` (SUCCESS)

`docker run --rm curlimages/curl -L -v https://app1.mydomain.net` (FAILS WITH TIMEOUT)

`docker run --rm --network host curlimages/curl -L -v https://app1.mydomain.net` (SUCCESS)

I'd appreciate any help. And sorry for the grammar, I'm not a native speaker.

Answer (score 1):

I feel this is a problem with your host routing. I was able to replicate this problem. On a fresh install, I was able to ping the host from within the container

host IP = 208.85.135.195  (changed for privacy, you will need to change the IP and device in the example below for your situation)

```
$ docker run -it --rm busybox
/ # ping bigboast.net
PING bigboast.net (208.85.135.195): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 208.85.135.195: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.077 ms
64 bytes from 208.85.135.195: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.272 ms
```

**My host route**

```
$ ip route
default via 208.85.135.1 dev enp3s0 onlink 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
208.85.135.0/24 dev enp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 208.85.135.195
```

Now the problem with the connectivity occurred when I added a new bridge network (via docker-compose).

busybox now times out

My Host route now

```
$ ip route show
default via 208.85.135.1 dev enp3s0 onlink 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-1723ac40a178 proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1 
208.85.135.0/24 dev enp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 208.85.135.195
```

**Solution / Fix**

replace the host route with this that includes a next hop router "via"

```
$ sudo ip route replace 208.85.135.0/24 via 208.85.135.1 dev enp3s0
```

Note: I found that if you create the new docker bridge networks first,  this did not always work. So best to do this on boot of the machine.

edit your /etc/network/interfaces and add the "up ip route replace 208.85.135.0/24 via 208.85.135.1 dev enp3s0" on your device. For example

```
auto enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet static
    address 208.85.135.195
    netmask 24
    gateway 208.85.135.1
    up ip route replace 208.85.135.0/24 via 208.85.135.1 dev enp3s0
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem.  It is because when a connection comes into the machine, there are iptables rules that rewrite the packet based on port number, so that it instead has a target IP address of the Docker container's internal IP instead of the host machine's IP.  This packet then gets sent to the right container based on its internal IP.

The problem is that these rules do not run when the packets originate from the local machine, so you end up trying to connect to the given port on the host, which is closed.  Normally the Docker container would intercept connections to this port making it look like the port is open, but in this case you're accessing the port directly on the host network, behind the Docker intercept.

There doesn't appear to be a way to cause local packets to traverse the DNAT iptables rules that map ports to container IPs, as this would fix the problem.

When I try I get the error:

```
x_tables: ip_tables: DNAT target: used from hooks PREROUTING/INPUT/OUTPUT,
  but only usable from PREROUTING/OUTPUT
```

A quick fix is to run the container with `--net=host` which will open the port on the host instead of using iptables rule rewriting.

The normal solution given is to use the IP address of the `docker0` network interface, however in my case this was not possible because I am running a DNS server in a container, and so my other containers are getting the IP from `/etc/resolv.conf`.  I can't change that to the Docker internal IP because it's coming from DHCP and would break DNS for other machines on the network, or other processes running on the host.  So I have no choice but to use the host IP from within the Docker containers.